# SQL Server Query to replace extra ";;;" characters

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have following rows in my table, i want to remove the duplicate semicolons(;).

```
ColumnName
Test;Test2;;;Test3;;;;Test4;
Test;;;Test2;Test3;;Test4;
Test;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;Test2;;;;Test3;;;;;Test4;
```

from the above rows, i want to remove the duplicate semicolons(;) and keep only one semicolon (;)

Like below

```
ColumnName
Test;Test2;Test3;Test4
Test;Test2;Test3;Test4
Test;Test2;Test3;Test4
```

Thanks
Rajesh

Comment: What you have tried so far??

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I like to use this pattern. AFAIK, originally posted by Jeff Moden on SQLServerCentral ([link](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/T-SQL/68378/)).
I've left the terminal semi-colon in all the rows as they are single occurance items. `SUBSTRING()` or `LEFT()` to remove.

```
CREATE TABLE #MyTable (MyColumn VARCHAR(500))
INSERT INTO #MyTable
SELECT 'Test;Test2;;;Test3;;;;Test4;'   UNION ALL
SELECT 'Test;;;Test2;Test3;;Test4;'     UNION ALL
SELECT 'Test;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;Test2;;;;Test3;;;;;Test4;' 

-- Where '^|' nor its revers '|^' is a sequence of characters that does not occur in the table\field
SELECT REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(MyColumn, ';', '^|'), '|^', ''), '^|', ';')
FROM #MyTable   

-- If you MUST remove terminal semi-colon
SELECT CleanText2   = LEFT(CleanText1, LEN(CleanText1)-1)
FROM
(
    SELECT CleanText1   = REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(MyColumn, ';', '^|'), '|^', ''), '^|', ';')
    FROM #MyTable
)DT
```

Comment: Hi Mark, Thank you for your quick solution. could you plese tell me how to remove last semicolan from the row?

Answer (score 1):

```
DECLARE @TestTable TABLE(Column1  NVARCHAR(MAX)) 

INSERT INTO @TestTable VALUES 
('Test;Test2;;;Test3;;;;Test4;'),
('Test;;;Test2;Test3;;Test4;'),
('Test;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;Test2;;;;Test3;;;;;Test4;')

SELECT        replace(
                  replace(
                     replace(
                        LTrim(RTrim(Column1)), 
                     ';;',';|'),                    
                  '|;',''),                         
               '|','') AS Fixed
 FROM @TestTable
```

**Result Set**

```
╔═════════════════════════╗
║          Fixed          ║
╠═════════════════════════╣
║ Test;Test2;Test3;Test4; ║
║ Test;Test2;Test3;Test4; ║
║ Test;Test2;Test3;Test4; ║
╚═════════════════════════╝
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT replace(replace(replace(Column1,';','<>'),'><',''),'<>',';') from table
```

try this

Its afaik i just replaced all ; by <> and then to ;